# Issue with timestamps & datetimes format (on the latest version of this package?) in yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "^9.20

Tags: datetime, datatable, timestamp, laravel-8, yajra-datatable

Timestamps are displayed with milliseconds. For example I have:

```
$users = User::select(['id', 'name', 'email', 'created_at', 'updated_at']);

        return Datatables::of($users)
            ->make(true);
```

and created_at is displayed like this:

```
2018-06-19T23:04:50.000000Z
```

Answer (score 0):

However, if I just add this:

```
->editColumn('created_at', function ($user) {
                return $user->created_at; // no formatting, just returned $user->created_at; 
            })
```

Then it will be displayed like this:

```
2022-06-19 23:04:50
```

So I didn't format or do anything with created_at, I just returned $user->created_at and in that case it's shown as expected.

Also, in DB in users table created_at values are like this: 2022-06-19 23:04:50.
Finally, I already have created_at in protected $dates in User.php model.

This is probably a bug because it didn't exist before I upgraded to the latest version of Laravel and yajra/laravel-datatables package.

- Operating System: Windows 10
- PHP Version: 7.3.11
- Laravel Version: 8.42.0
- Laravel-Datatables Version: 9.18.0